# Dockerfile alternative for VM

Tags: virtual-machines, docker

Dockerfile helps a lot in terms tracking the packages being installed and needed on the system, but I couldn't find any reliable alternative to manage a VM and spawn it back with the same state as before.

making an AMI helps in the aspect of spawning it back to the same state but it doesn't help much to review or check the modifications done to the VM.

so is there any alternative of Dockerfile for VM,

- to track the packages being installed on a VM
- any changes i.e file changes like config, etc,
- network changes etc,..
- spawn a similar VM on demand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer from Hashicorp has a concept of packer files that have a similar purpose. https://www.packer.io/

There are a lot of examples of using these, for example, https://github.com/boxcutter

Answer (score 2):

Write install scripts that can take a base OS install to the desired state. Add logging as required. Commit these to a version control system.

Use your preferred flavor of configuration management or automation tool to help write the scripts. They are good at installing software and templates for configuration. Possibly they will help with logging and reporting on configuration differences.

Decide how you deploy and manage. You might be able to deploy a new VM every time, either from a template VM or your "bare metal" install scripts.  Otherwise, you will also need the ability to apply changes to already running hosts.